# Unable to call the Snowflake procedure with argumet from ADF Script activity

Tags: azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory

I'm really struggling to call the snowflake procedure with an argument from Azure Data Factory Script Activity.

```
CALL data_validation_procedure('google_table');
```

But this script to call the procedure works well when I run this query in the Snowflake worksheet but not in ADF script Activity

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wA8Q8.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UvWl.png

Is there any reason why I'm encountering this problem?
Any solution or Alternatives for this?

Comment: Does the program know which database and schema to use in Snowflake when you are calling the procedure?

Comment: Do you see any error when running the script from ADF? Or from the Snowflake history do you see any error for the run operation from ADF?

Comment: Can you share the pipeline definition or screenshots of activity configuration and linked service? The error message indicates that the connection is to some Microsoft service and not Snowflake. Are you sure you used the Snowflake connection?

Comment: @psabela yes store procedure exactly know all the detail about the database and schema to use in snowflake. If I execute the same store procedure with parameter in snowflake it works perfectly well for me but when I call the same procedure via ADF I'm facing this issue

Comment: @MichaelGolos Yes, the linked service is exactly working well for me. If I call another store procedure without passing argument then it exactly works for me. But calling the store procedure with arguments causes this problem for me

Comment: @SrinathMenon yes the error while calling procedure is attached in my above question. So as you mentioned when I go back and check the history of the snowflake I didn't see any error/run operations

Comment: @ShekharKhadka did you resolve this? I have the same issue. Only links I've found are https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1251465/how-to-use-script-parameters-in-an-azure-data-fact

Comment: @Asher I've attached my findings in the answer section.
Thank You

Answer (score 2):

After going through lots of huddles and consulting with a few colleagues, finally, I could able to figure out the cause of this problem with a solution.

Actually, there is no wrong with the procedure and Script Activity of ADF code.

The main problem for this cause is due to conflict caused by  `into` **keywords** used in our procedure and `ADF SCRIPT ACTIVITY` where we use these `into` keywords in procedure SQL Sccript while assigning the value in the declared value which is actually not supported with the ADF Script Activity.
**for example**

```
Create or replace procedure ........
..........
DECLARE
max_value int;
BEGIN

SELECT MAX(dep_id) INTO:max_value FROM EMPLOYEE_TABLE
....
END;
....
```

In this case, while assigning the maximum **dep_id** to **max_value** ADF Script Activity will crash like above.

And till date, it is totally abstract for me why this ADF activity is not supporting the `into` keywords in Snowflake.

**SOLUTION**

To resolve it, a straightforward solution is not to use the **INTO** keywords in your procedure that is to be called from the ADF activity.

The above SQL can be re-written as below;

```
Create or replace procedure ........
..........
DECLARE
max_value int;
BEGIN

max_value=: (SELECT MAX(dep_id)  FROM EMPLOYEE_TABLE);
....
END;
....
```

But if your requirement is mandatory to use the `INTO` keywords then better to go with a nested procedure like below;

1. Create one driver procedure named `A` which will be called from the ADF and this procedure shouldn't contain any `INTO` keywords.
2. Create another procedure `B` with the `into` keywords in the script.
3. Call the procedure `B` from procedure `A`